# How to save an array of objects to the database really fast in Rails3?

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have an really big array of objects read from a CSV file and want to save it to the database.
This is what I am doing:

```
# Read CSV
... each do |values|
  new_value = Model.new
  ... # fill properties
  @new_values.push new_value # put it into the array
end

# now save them to the database
@new_values.each do |new_value| 
    new_value.save :validate => false
    @added_counter += 1
end
```

But this is really slow because it will make a statement for each element in the array. How can this be done in a fast and correct way?

Comment: I am using MySQL and the models get created and then get lots of popertys from the CSV file (around 30 integers or floats, each).

Comment: Have you considered leaving AR out of it and going straight to SQL or even just letting MySQL import the CSV all by itself? AR isn't exactly a speed demon.

Comment: I need to validate the data when reading the CSV file, because its given by the user. But building a custom sql-statement seems like a way to go. I will try that.

Comment: You could import into a temp table, the do your validations in the database, and then do a bulk copy to the real table. A bit ugly and not overly DRY but if speed is your primary requirement then you go what you have to do; OTOH, I'm as comfortable with SQL as Ruby. Just something to think about.

Comment: you can also try NoSQL solution as temporary DB to store data before validation and move to the real production-use database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe [activerecord-import](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import) could be useful for you.

It allows to do something like:

```
books = []
10.times do |i| 
  books << Book.new(:name => "book #{i}")
end
Book.import books
```

Comment: Ah nice. Much nicer than doing this by hand.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution based on the comments of **mu is too short** (Thanks!).
I use a handmade SQL-Statement and execute it.

```
  insert_statement = "INSERT INTO table_name (custom_property_from_parameter"
  # the properties from the model are fetched by a method, to keep it a little bit generic, loop trough them and give their names to the statement
  Model.parameter_names.each do |parameter|
    insert_statement += "," + parameter
  end
  insert_statement += ") VALUES "
  @new_values.each do |new_value|
    insert_statement += "(" + params[:custom_property]
    Model.parameter_names.each do |parameter|
      # Rails' nil has to be converted into NULL for SQL
      if nil == new_value.send(parameter)
        insert_statement += ",NULL"
      else
        insert_statement += "," + new_value.send(parameter).to_s
      end
    end
    insert_statement += "),"
    @added_counter += 1
  end
  # Remove the last , with ;
  insert_statement = insert_statement[0..-2]
  insert_statement += ";"
  # now execute the statement
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute insert_statement
```

This solution takes approximately a third of the time. But it seems a little bit like a hack to me.

Comment: This is the kind of code that activerecord-import is used to help avoid having to write. It handles intelligently converting the data you're importing based on your column definitions in your AR-models. It will also ensure that it executes the least amount of import statements for RDBMS's like MySQL, where you could otherwise get a MAX PACKET ALLOWED exceeded error.